# Nokogiri builder #to_xml, no carriage return after adding text fragments

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri 1.10.3 and Ruby 2.4.5.

I have a number of complex XML text strings to add to a document that has a standard header composite. I'm doing it using Builder to create the document with the header, then iterate through the strings to add them in.

When using `to_xml` carriage returns and beginning-of-line indentations are being lost from the document except for where they appear in the XML strings that have been added.

It appears to be only when the XML strings themselves contain "`\n`".

Examples:

Good: Builder without XML strings being added. The resulting XML string has carriage returns and indents:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end
end ; 0

xml.to_xml

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Message>\n  <Header>\n    <NumberOne>1</NumberOne>\n    <NumberTwo>2</NumberTwo>\n  </Header>\n</Message>\n"
```

Note the "`\n`" and spaces between `</NumberOne>` and `<NumberTwo>`, for example.

Good: Builder with XML strings being added, and XML strings have no carriage returns. The resulting XML string has carriage returns and indents:

```
xml_text1 = "<text>text1</text>"

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end
  xml << xml_text1
end ; 0

xml.to_xml

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Message>\n  <Header>\n    <NumberOne>1</NumberOne>\n    <NumberTwo>2</NumberTwo>\n  </Header>\n  <text>text1</text>\n</Message>\n"
```

Bad: Builder with XML strings being added, and XML strings *do* have carriage returns. The resulting XML string has carriage returns and indents removed except when the XML strings inserted had them:

```
xml_text1 = "<text1>text1</text1>\n<text2>text2</text2>"

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end
  xml << xml_text1
end ; 0

xml.to_xml

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Message><Header><NumberOne>1</NumberOne><NumberTwo>2</NumberTwo></Header><text1>text1</text1>\n<text2>text2</text2></Message>\n"
```

Note that the "`\n`" and spaces have been removed.

It would be legitimate for the XML content to have carriage returns in, so using `gsub` to remove all carriage returns out of the strings would not be an option for me I'm afraid.

Is there another way to include these text strings that might not trigger such a problem?

---

As @igneus points out, it is the presence of any text between the XML elements that causes this behaviour.

So as an example:

```
xml_text1 = "<text1>tex<b> <b>t1</text1> <text2>text2</text2>"

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end
  xml << xml_text1.gsub(/>\n {0,}</, "><")
end ; 0

xml.to_xml

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<Message><Header><NumberOne>1</NumberOne><NumberTwo>2</NumberTwo></Header><text1>tex<b> <b>t1</b></b></text1> <text2>text2</text2></Message>\n"
```

In fact when the text string is converted to a fragment we see extra `Nokogiri::XML::Text` objects containing a space, or in the previous examples with "`\n`", "`\n`", etc.

```
xml_text1 = "<text1>tex<b> <b>t1</text1> <text2>text2</text2>"

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")

=> #<Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment:0x3fff1805bcb4 name="#document-fragment" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff1805b700 name="text1" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff1805a4f4 "tex">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff1805a3b4 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff19a93fc8 " ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff19a93dac name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff19a93a3c "t1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff19a93730 " ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fff19a9358c name="text2" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fff19a93258 "text2">]>]>]>]>
```

These elements are not ignored by `to_xml`.

```
xml.doc.fragment(xml_text1).to_xml(indent: 0)
 => "<text1>tex<b> <b>t1</b> <text2>text2</text2></b></text1>"
```

So would a passable solution be something that removes those Text elements?

Comment: "It appears to be only when the XML strings themselves contain `\n`." Actually the behaviour doesn't depend on the string containing newline, but on whitespace _between XML elements_.

Comment: One more generalization: actually it depends on _any text content between XML elements_

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! I'll test regenerating the text fragments without indents to see if that is a workable fix. Thanks for spotting that @igneus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML serialization is handled by the underlying libxml2. ["If libxml2 detects that there is already some text nodes as children of a node it will disable automatic indenting for the whole subtree."](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2009-June/msg00042.html) AFAIK this libxml2 behaviour cannot be changed.

In your example such a text node was produced by the newline between elements, but the same happens for any inter-element text. Since the text node was added to the root element, the whole document was rendered without indentation. Were it added somewhere down the document structure, only the subtree containing it would lack indentation:

```
xml_text1 = "<text1>text1</text1>a<text2>text2</text2>"
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end
  # wrapper element added
  xml.Wrapper do
    xml << xml_text1
  end
end

puts xml.to_xml
```

Only the content of `<Wrapper>` is without indentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message>
  <Header>
    <NumberOne>1</NumberOne>
    <NumberTwo>2</NumberTwo>
  </Header>
  <Wrapper><text1>text1</text1>a<text2>text2</text2></Wrapper>
</Message>
```

A possibly useful hack would be parsing the XML strings yourself and removing the unwanted text elements:

```
xml_text1 = "<text1>text1</text1>\n<text2>text2</text2>"

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: "utf-8")
xml.Message do
  xml.Header do
    xml.NumberOne "1"
    xml.NumberTwo "2"
  end

  doc.fragment(xml_text1).children.each do |node|
    # drop all whitespace-only text nodes
    next if node.text? && node.content =~ /\A\s+\Z/
    insert node
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent information. For my particular case I might end up (horror) 'gsubbing' the xml string before it gets turned into a fragment, looking for the closure of an element, '\n', and some number of spaces before the start of a new element.